# SQL Server: Calculating Page Life Expectancy

Tags: sql-server, performance

I want to calculate the page life expectancy of my SQL Server.
If I query the PLE with the follwowing query I get the value 46.000:

```
SELECT [object_name],
[counter_name],
[cntr_value] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Manager%'
AND [counter_name] = 'Page life expectancy'
```

I think this value isn't the final value because of the high amount. Do I have to calculate these value with a specifiy formula?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some counters reported by `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` are cumulative, PLE reflects the current value so no calculation is necessary.

As to whether the value of 46 seconds is a cause for concern depends much on the workload and storage system. This value would be concern on a high-volume OLTP system with local spinning disk media due to the multi-millisecond latency incurred for each physical IO and IOPS of roughly 200 per spindle. Conversely, the same workload with high-performance local SSD may be fine because the storage capable of well over 100K IOPS.

Comment: So I understand right?:
PLE with 46.000 seconds could be normal on my server? This server is our test sql server with 46 databases on there. (VM with SAN-Storage)

Comment: With SAN storage, a PLE value of 46 seconds is a cause of concern for performance, IMHO. More memory and/or query/index tuning may be in order.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought the value in cntr_value means seconds. But it means milliseconds, right?

Comment: @ssd_rider, the value is in seconds.

Comment: So and if I have a SQL Server with cntr_value with 2557, so the page life expectancy is 2 seconds??? (When a value of 46000 is 46 seconds?!?) Thx

Comment: @ssd_rider, 2557 seconds is 42 minutes and 37 seconds. The value 46.000 in your original question is 46 whole seconds since the fractional seconds is zero.